# Grouping redis.get for 2ms and then executing by mget

Tags: node.js, redis

My application makes about 50 `redis.get` call to serve a single http request, it serves millions of request daily and application runs on about 30 pods.

When monitoring on newrelic i am getting 200MS average `redis.get` time, To Optimize this i wrote a simple pipeline system in nodejs which is simply a wrapper over `redis.get` and it pushes all the request in queue, and then execute the queue using `redis.mget` (getting all the keys in bulk).

Following is the code snippet:

```js
class RedisBulk {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = [];
    this.processingQueue = {};
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this._processQueue();
    }, 5);
  }
  clear() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
  get(key, cb) {
    this.queue.push({cb, key});
  }

  _processQueue() {
    if (this.queue.length > 0) {
      let queueLength = this.queue.length;
      logger.debug('Processing Queue of length', queueLength);
      let time = (new Date).getTime();
      this.processingQueue[time] = this.queue;
      this.queue = []; //empty the queue

      let keys = [];
      this.processingQueue[time].forEach((item)=> {
        keys.push(item.key);
      });
      global.redisClient.mget(keys, (err, replies)=> {
        if (err) {
          captureException(err);
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          this.processingQueue[time].forEach((item, index)=> {
            item.cb(err, replies[index]);
          });
        }
        delete  this.processingQueue[time];
      });
    }
  }
}

let redis_bulk = new RedisBulk();

redis_bulk.get('a');
redis_bulk.get('b');
redis_bulk.get('c');
redis_bulk.get('d');
```

My Question is: is this a good approach? will it help in optimizing redis get time? is there any other solution for above problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a redis expert but judging by the documentation ;

**MGET** has the time complexity of

> O(N) where N is the number of keys to retrieve.

And **GET** has the time complexity of

> O(1)

Which brings both scenarios to the same end result in terms of time complexity in your scenario. Having a bulk request with MGET can bring you some improvements for the IO but apart from that looks like you have the same bottleneck.

*I'd ideally split my data into chunks, responding via multiple http requests in async fashion if that's an option.*

Alternatively, you can try calling GET with `promise.all()` to run GET requests in parallel, for all the GET calls you need.

Something like;

```
const asyncRedis = require("async-redis");
const client = asyncRedis.createClient();

function bulk() {
  const keys = [];
  return Promise.all(keys.map(client.get))
}
```